# Get the json data

Tags: json, twitter

I was just trying out a simple authentication with Twitter API and I got the json value. I read the json contents as usual and everything works fine. When I get the json from tweets url, I couldn't be able to read the tweets value.

Below is how the json data is retrieved from the url http://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json

Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [created_at] => Tue Oct 08 13:40:08 +0000 2013 [id] => 3.8757312415518E+17 [id_str] => 387573124155183104 [text] => Keep calm and read your stats. 12 new followers and 4 unfollowers. Daily stats via http://t.co/9XzBTh21tj [source] => JustUnfollow [truncated] => [in_reply_to_status_id] => [in_reply_to_status_id_str] => [in_reply_to_user_id] => [in_reply_to_user_id_str] => [in_reply_to_screen_name] => [user] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 501484306

I called the object as

```
$tweet=$content->text;
echo $tweet;
```

Please, anyone help me to get tweet only from the json data.

Answer (score 1):

Okay..!! I got the answer.

```
echo $tweets[0]->text;
```

This solves my problem.